# Is there anyway in python to retrieve a line from a .txt file randomly, then print it and do this multiple times without repeating the same one?

Tags: python

currently, I can only randomly select a line. but I don't know how to prevent it from being repeated. how would I do this?

```
  Proxy = None
  for line in fileinput.input("file.path"):
      if random.randrange(fileinput.lineno()) == 0:
        Proxy = line
```

Comment: try to save the randomly selected line no in a list  and when the same line no repeated ,ignore it and try again

Comment: You could use `random.sample(fileinput.lineno())`.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider selecting the line number and then removing it from the source, which would work until you run out of samples.
Either that or memoization can help you ignore already selected samples.

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep all the file in memory you can use `random` in order to shuffle it and then print the shuffled lines.

```
import random
random.sample(lines, len(lines))
```

You can also shuffle them in place using `random.shuffle(lines)`

Answer (score 0):

If your file doesn't have 78 billion lines, you can use this:

```py
with open("file.path") as f:
    Proxy = random.choice(f.readlines())
```

If you don't want the whole file in your memory, you can use this:

```py
def get_random_line():
    lines_to_skip = 0
    with open("file.path") as f:
        lines_to_skip = sum(1 for line in f)
    choice = random.randint(0, lines_to_skip)
    with open("file.path") as f:
        for line in f:
            if lines_to_skip <= 0:
                return line
            lines_to_skip -= 1
```

It opens the file twice. The first loop is to count the lines and in the second loop it grabs the chosen line